# Path not found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I installed SignalR 2.0-rc1, and:

1: Created a hub:

```
public class Socials : Hub
{
    public void PublicChat(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.PublicChat(new { message });
    }
}
```

2: Created a startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

3: Registered it in web.config:

```
<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Scyk.Startup, Scyk"/> //Scyk is my main namespace, also a project name, I placed Startup class in there.
```

Now, `https://myhost.com/signalr/hubs` is generating javascript file properly, but when I open developer console in my browser, I see that it has not connected, but:

1. There is an asp error saying that path /signalr/connect was not found (why is it trying to access /signalr/connect? Is that normal? If so, then this must be purely routing problem, how do I solve it?)
2. In my console, I see that there is a `EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.` error. I am not sure if this is related, but it started to show up today, wasn't there before.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Any path beginning with /signalr should be routed through OWIN so signalr can handle the request.

It is normal for the client to try to access /signalr/connect after accessing /signalr/negotiate. /signalr/connect is the endpoint where SignalR establishes its WebSockets/Server-Sent Events/Forever Frame/Long Polling connections.